# Razorpay issue - flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on flutter web app where i have implemented razorpay in my web app.
so razorpay working on local database but not working when I deployed website (on a custom domain).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHrfw.png)

Comment: can you share  razorpay code, are you use razorpay plugin ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.